# How to add-content to a log file without overwriting?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a code which will produce a log file. But everytime when the code got executed, I want it to be added to the same log file without overwriting the previous content. I have tried using add-content but it is overwriting the previous content.

Below is my code to generate log file:-

```
#generate log file
$Logfile = "C:\path\zipprocess.log"

Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

LogWrite(write-zip $temp ( "$temp.zip"))
```

How can I keep on adding contents to the log file generated at the first time the code got executed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Function LogWrite {
   Param ([string]$logstring)
   $logstring >> $Logfile
}
```

Or you can use the following to append to a file:

```
$logstring | Out-File -FilePath $Logfile -Append
```